# ANDROID App crash when installed in device: JSException: Can't find variable: Promise (RN 0.57.1)

Tags: android, react-native

Android app installs but crashes on open in devices, but in debug mode works perfectly.

You can see the crash report below

```
2019-03-15 15:02:50.685 4431-4515/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{8cd349a u0 Splash Screen com.sample EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0, caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:748 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:732 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5646 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:553 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.lambda$-com_android_server_wm_DisplayContent_21578:476 
2019-03-15 15:02:51.555 970-1030/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
Process: com.sample, PID: 970
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Can't find variable: props, stack:
value@285:1369
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:54)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-03-15 15:02:51.989 4431-4515/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{bb689b5 u0 com.sample/com.sample.MainActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8, caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:748 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:732 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5646 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:553 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.lambda$-com_android_server_wm_DisplayContent_21578:476
```

Comment: Can you post your `index.js`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow this issue: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/197:

> When using react-native bundle (the command that runs when you build a
>   release), InitializeCore.js is not the first file that get required,
>   but instead it is required later, sometime during the generation of
>   the bridge method, randomly (which is why if you are lucky or not
>   using Promise // setTimeout early you'll be fine) iOS does not need
>   all those polyfills which is why the issue is only detected on android
>   in release mode.